# CSS - get 3 divs in a line with text on bottom?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Im just having a frustrating time trying to emulate this - where the arrows function as buttons and text sits below the img -

[image]

For CSS, Ive tried as other questions suggest:

```
.ico-selector {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 123px;
  float: left;
}
```

---

### Example

```css
.ico-selector {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 123px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ico-selector">
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <img src="https://d1j8pt39hxlh3d.cloudfront.net/development/emojione/2.2/843/2270.svg" />
  <p>My Icon</p>
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

but they remain vertically stacked. How can I do this?

Comment: float always implies display: block. using inline-block with float, does not make sense

Comment: What does JavaScript and jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: The question got closed, but [I made a flexbox solution here](https://jsfiddle.net/c3mn3547/).

Comment: @TemaniAfif enough dupes? :) this is a basic question asked way too much in here, that a simple search would solve it

Comment: That's why I added 3 more dupes using non-block elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```css
.ico-selector {
  width: 123px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*adjust these values as you need*/
.ico-selector img {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.ico-selector>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ico-selector">
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <img src="https://d1j8pt39hxlh3d.cloudfront.net/development/emojione/2.2/843/2270.svg" />
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  <p>My Icon</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `ico-selector` box has fixed dimensions. Why not just position the chevrons absolutely within that box?

```
.ico-selector {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 123px;
}
.fa-chevron-left{
position: absolute;
left:0;
top: 50%;
}
.fa-chevron-right{
position: absolute;
right:0;
top: 50%;
}
```

Its a rather rough example but it illustrates the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use divs to surround each part of your icon selector like this:

```css
.ico-selector {
  width: 123px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.left-arrow, .icon, .right-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ico-selector">
  <div class="left-arrow">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://d1j8pt39hxlh3d.cloudfront.net/development/emojione/2.2/843/2270.svg" />
    <p>My Icon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-arrow">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```